# Como atualizar com AJAX uma lista após a ação de um formulário remoto?

Tags: ajax, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Estou com um problema que nunca tive em Java mas estou quase ficando louco em Rails.
Eu estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde existem usuários e grupos. Então criei um model separado para relacionamento `N:N` entre usuários e grupos.

Na página show de grupos eu criei a descrição do grupo, logo abaixo aparece a partial de formulário `_groupsuser` para permitir que o criador do grupo adicione usuários aquele grupo. Abaixo de tudo isso eu renderizei a partial para exibir a listagem de usuários pertencentes ao grupo.

O projeto ficou com uma estrutura um pouco diferente porque estou usando partials para evitar ficar replicando a mesma lógica no controle e na view portanto gostaria de evitar ficar mexendo na estrutura e focar apenas em atualizar a listagem assim que tiver a resposta `'ajax:complete'`. No caso criei no controle o metodo create:

```ruby
def create
    if group.user == current_user       
        @groupsuser = Groupsuser.new(groupsuser_params)
        @groupsuser.group = group
        if @groupsuser.save
            flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully add.'
        else
            flash[:alert] = 'User cannot be add.'
        end
    else
        flash[:notice] = "You didn't have permition."
    end
    head :ok
end
```

Gostaria de fazer a atualização usando apenas ajax semelhante ao metodo update do java com facelets tipo:

```
    <p:commandButton value="All" id="btnAll" process="@all" update="grid"   
                actionListener="#{personBean.savePerson}"/>
```

Por exemplo:

```js
$('create_button').onClick('ajax:complete', render(@group));
```

para atualizar a página inteira ou

```js
$('create_button').onClick('ajax:complete', "Comando mágico para atualizar apenas a div");
```

Comment: Qual o problema que você encontrou? Se isso não funciona, como exatamente não funciona? O que você acontece?

Comment: Então, eu não sou muito fera em javaScript mas tentei de tudo que é jeito e o usuário é adicionado na tabela groupsuser perfeitamente. No entanto não atualiza a página automaticamente. Quando eu mando atualizar manualmente aparecem os comentários do :notice e o usuário na listagem, mas gostaria de implementar uma forma onde assim que eu clicar em add a página já atualiza para mostrar a notificação e o usuário na listagem. Eu já tentei usar o render e o redirect_to (apesar de perder a notificação) mas não atualiza a página automaticamente.

Comment: Eu não sei se essa minha idéia funciona porque andei dando uma olhada no SO em inglês e encontrei pessoas arrumando soluções adversas pra mim não funciona porque a rota groupsuser está dentro da groups no routes.rb. Será que não tem uma forma de atualizar a página juntamente com as informações que vem do backend @gropsuser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de tudo, estude a gem [Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) para implementar as permissões.

Com a Cancan, o código do seu método ficaria assim:

```
def create
    @groupsuser = Groupsuser.new(groupsuser_params)
    @groupsuser.group = group
    if @groupsuser.save
        flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully add.'
    else
        flash[:alert] = 'User cannot be add.'
    end
end
```

Agora para fazer o cadastro de usuário por Ajax, primeiro adicione a opção `remote: true` ao seu form de cadastro. Com isso, você não precisa adicionar código JS para o form fazer POST com Ajax.

Depois, adicione o código no fim da action create. Esse código indica que a requisição será do tipo `javascript`.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
end
```

Por último, crie a view create.js.erb, que contém o código JS que deve ser executado na resposta da requisição. Deve ser algo do tipo:

```
$('div#users-container').html('<%= j render(@group.users) %>');
```

Com esse código, não é necessário adicionar listener JS "na mão".
A opção `remote: true` está disponível pela biblioteca [jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs).

Comment: Então, eu implementei a sua sugestão e percebi que está executando ok mas no render do create.js.erb está direcionando para uma rota que não é válida. ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial group/users/user

Comment: Eu tentei mudar o render para ` $('div#users-container').html('<%= j render(group_path) %>'); ` e resolveu o problema de rota mas ficou faltando o parâmetro :id que serve para carregar o grupo em  ` group_model = Group.find(params[:id])
 @group = GroupPresenter.new(group_model, self)
 @usergroups = Groupsuser.where(group: group_model) `

Comment: Você deve adicionar o `:id` na rota. Um exemplo seria: `'/groups/:id/users'`

Comment: No `routes.rb`? Aí tem uma outra dúvida também. Eu não preciso acessar o users porque o `show.html.erb` em que estão estas funcionalidades que estou fazendo fica dentro do diretório 'views/groups/show.html.erb' e o 'create.js.er'b eu tive que criar dentro de `views/**group**/groupsusers/create.js.erb` , será que não seria só alterar o render e enviar o `:id` como: `:id => @group.id` ?

Comment: Eu tentei com `´$('div#users-container').html('<%= j render group_path(@group)  %>');´` e aparece o seguinte erro: 
`'´ActionView::Template::Error (The partial name (/pt-BR/groups/21) is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial
name starts with a lowercase letter or underscore, and is followed by any combination of letters, numbers and underscore
s.)`'´

Comment: @brunowff, o método `render` recebe o caminho de uma **view** e não de uma **rota**. [Lê isso aqui antes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). O método `render` deve receber o caminho da partial que cria a div com todos os seus usuários. Por exemplo, `render partial: 'groups/users'`, renderiza o arquivo `app/view/groups/_users.html.erb`.

Comment: Sim mas como eu estou passando o valor de `@usergroups` através de `<%= render partial: 'groupsusers', locals: {usergroups: @usergroups}, remote: true %>` e listando através de `<% @usergroups.each do |g| %>` quando eu renderizo apenas a partial `_groupsusers.html.erb` o valor de @usergroups fica nil e não define o método each. `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method each' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: `remote: true` é uma opção do `form_for`, não do `render`.

Comment: vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12850/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-brunowff)